# jQuery onclick in for each selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click a `button` div, I want to add a class named `active` to the `popup` div that has the corresponding class name in the `data-trigger` attribute.

For example if I click on the div with class name `button-two`, the div with `data-trigger="button-two"` should get class `active`.

The issue: `active` is added only to the last `popup` div. How can I make this work?

Here's what I have tried:

```js
$('.popup').each(function() {

  popupObj = $(this);
  var popupTrigger = popupObj.data("trigger");

  $('.' + popupTrigger).click(function() {
    popupObj.addClass('active');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-one">Test 1</div>
<div class="button-two">Test 2</div>
<div class="button-three">Test 3</div>

<div class="popup" data-trigger="button-one">Hello world</div>
<div class="popup" data-trigger="button-two">Hello there</div>
<div class="popup" data-trigger="button-three">Hello again</div>
```

Comment: seems weird the data-trigger is not on the element you are clicking.... but your issue is global variable. A good linter hooked up to your IDE would have pointed out the undeclared variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you did not declare `popupObj` as a local variable; It is global, and so it will have changed in the last iteration of the `each`: it is *that* value that will be referenced in all three click handlers.

Remember that `each` will have performed all iterations before any of the click handlers get called.

Solution: use `var popupObj`. That way each of the click handlers will reference their "own" variable.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the issue! As far as the for each loop/logic, would you say this is the right way to do it?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine to me. Of course, there are many ways to achieve the same, but this way is certainly a good candidate.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to use `data` attribute also for buttons .. and make only one click event for the buttons .. see the next example

```js
$('.button[data-to-trigger]').on('click' , function(){
    var GetTriggerDiv = $(this).attr('data-to-trigger');
    $('.popup').removeClass('active').filter('.popup[data-trigger="'+GetTriggerDiv+'"]').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button" data-to-trigger="button-one">Test 1</div>
<div class="button" data-to-trigger="button-two">Test 2</div>
<div class="button" data-to-trigger="button-three">Test 3</div>

<div class="popup" data-trigger="button-one">Hello world</div>
<div class="popup" data-trigger="button-two">Hello there</div>
<div class="popup" data-trigger="button-three">Hello again</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "each" function in jQuery returns 2 values: index and element. Try using the element returned instead of $(this).

```
$('.popup').each(function(index, element) {

    var popupTrigger = element.data("trigger");

    $('.'+popupTrigger).click(function() {
        element.addClass('active');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that matches the popup to the button using the same data trigger for both:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    var trigger = $(this).data("trigger");
    $('.popup').each(function() {
      if ($(this).data("trigger") == trigger) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn" data-trigger="button-one">Test 1</div>
<div class="btn" data-trigger="button-two">Test 2</div>
<div class="btn" data-trigger="button-three">Test 3</div>

<div class="popup" data-trigger="button-one">Hello world</div>
<div class="popup" data-trigger="button-two">Hello there</div>
<div class="popup" data-trigger="button-three">Hello again</div>
```